# Why does app.use(app.static(...)); does not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to programming in general. Currently learning about Javascript, node.js, and express...

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
```

Why does **app.use(express.static(path.join(...)));** works while  **app.use(app.static(path.join(...)));** does not work?

Aren't they the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aren't they the same thing?

No.

The return value of a function is not the same thing as the function.

> What does it mean when I assign a function to a variable? const app = express()

You are not assigning a function to a variable. You are assigning the return value of a function to a variable.

```js
function add(a, b) { return a + b };

const assignAFunction = add;
const assignTheReturnValue = add(1,1);

console.log({ assignAFunction, assignTheReturnValue });
```

Comment: Thank you! const app = express();  What does express(); return? I guess the return value is an object?

Comment: @JiayingLin - `express()` is a factory function.  That means when you call it, it creates a new object and returns that object (it's like a factory for new objects).  In this case, it's returning an Express `app` object which you can then use to configure your web server.  This is all described in the Express documentation.